# How to Save Selection in Angularjs UI - Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I built this `ui-grid` that updates every 3 seconds:

```
function updateGrid() {
dFactory.getData().then(function(data) {
       $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
});
```

The data updates just fine, but the selection deletes itself, the rows I select before just won't save.

I have tried:

1. Putting primary key - didn't help
2. Saving state and restore it after update - didn't help
3. Manually select rows after update - didn't help

What can i do?

Comment: can you post more code? this doesn't help at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved it:

```
var state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
                $scope.mydata = response.data;

                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.gridApi.saveState.restore($scope, state);
                }, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

User selection (row selected) state need to be kept in your data model.
Add a new field such as 'selection' to keep states of each rows in grid.
Then each time user select a row, call a method to update selection state:

```
$scope.updateSelection(row)
{
   dFactory.updateSelectedRow(row);
   // do other stuffs
}
```